# How to get the database name from a sys.all_objects consult

Tags: sql, t-sql, schema

```
SELECT so.name, so.object_id AS ID, so.type_desc,SCHEMA_NAME ( so.schema_id)  
FROM sys.all_objects so
WHERE so.name LIKE '%'+@search+'%'
```

I want to add the object database name to this query but I don't know where to find the key field to do the join.

Comment: Isn't that always limited to the current database?

Answer (score 4):

The `sys.objects` view includes all objects created within the current database (including those shipped by Microsoft, which are marked in the `is_ms_shipped` column). These objects can be tables, views, stored procedures, constraints, user-defined functions, etc.

The `sys.system_objects` view includes all system objects. These objects are accessible from any database, but are not stored within the current database. Their definition is in the Resource Database (mssqlsystemresource.mdf), a hidden, read-only database, which cannot be acessed in the usual way.

The `sys.all_objects` view contains a UNION between sys.objects and `sys.system_objects`. If you want to search for objects that are created by the user, you should use the `sys.objects` view instead of the `sys.all_objects` view.

If you want to know the name of the current database, you can use the `DB_NAME()` function.

If you want to search for an object in all databases, you could use a cursor or (if it's a one-time thing) the undocumented stored procedure `sp_MSforeachdb`:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL='USE ? SELECT name, object_id, type_desc, SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id), DB_NAME() FROM sys.objects WHERE name LIKE ''%'+REPLACE(@search,'''','''''''')+'%'''
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @search sysname

SET @search='xyz'

SELECT DB_NAME()[DATABASE],
    so.name,
    so.object_id AS ID,
    so.type_desc,
    SCHEMA_NAME ( so.schema_id)  
FROM sys.all_objects so
WHERE so.name LIKE '%'+@search+'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it's an old post, but still very useful & applicable, therefore here is my addition. Solution uses `sp_MSForEachDb` (as other answers) but renders output in much cleaner/readable and exportable format.

Essentially, as by default the output generated by the `sp_MSForEachDb` is split into separate panes which makes it very difficult to copy/export out all the result-sets in one go.

To overcome above issue and to get all the resultsets in an exportable output (as a single resultset), all we need to do is first store the resultsets in to a #temp table then retrieve output from there, following is the full working example that searches an object-name in each database (along with other essential information including the database-name as asked in the question):

```
DECLARE @obj_to_find VARCHAR(999) = 'your_object_name_here'
drop table if exists #searchResults
SELECT top 1 name, object_id, SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS [schema_name], DB_NAME() [DB_Name], type, type_desc, create_date, modify_date 
INTO #searchResults FROM sys.objects WHERE 0 = 1;
DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(999);
SET @qry='USE [?]; INSERT INTO #searchResults SELECT name, object_id, SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS [schema_name], DB_NAME() [DB_Name], type, type_desc, create_date, modify_date FROM sys.objects WHERE name LIKE ''%'+REPLACE(@obj_to_find,'''','''''''')+'%'''
exec sp_MSforeachdb @qry
select * from #searchResults
```

HTH.

In addition to above, one can install [free search tool from Red-Gate©](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/installer/) called "*SQL Search*" which does excellent job (disclaimer: I'm not being sponsored for mentioning this tool).